# Doubleclick open all type of file directly in text editor

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a problem with Unity and I hope you can help me because, actually, I don't understand.

For each double click on any file, even the scenes or other internal type, Unity open it directly inside Sublime3.

Does anyone know how to fix?

ADD:

The problem is that EVERYTHING now opens with that, even the scenes and the prefabs

if I double click on the scene or the prefab and it opens sublime with the binary 0001010010101

Comment: Go to edit->preferences->external tool the setting should be there

Comment: yes, I have sublime3 as a setting.

The problem is that EVERYTHING now opens with that, even the scenes and the prefabs

Comment: if I double click on the scene or the prefab and it opens sublime with the binary 0001010010101

Comment: ok... Quite right. Simply remove Sublime from the list.

Edit > ExternalTools and flag "external script editor" in "Open by file extension"

That's all. Thank you

(A nonsense but ok, it happens :D )

Answer (score 1):

Just to be clear, cause I was confused a bit, what you should do is to go in the Edit->Preferences->External Tools and there under External Script Editor choose Open By File extension. This way script files will open with Sublime3 (or whatever you had set up before), and scene files will open in unity properpy.